# cakephp 3.x create custom widget

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to create widget for Cakephp formHelper.

I created  a widget file named ImageWidget.php in View/Widget directory (I don't know if this is the right directory but phpstorm loads it so it seems fine)

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Widget;

use Cake\View\Form\ContextInterface;
use Cake\View\Widget\WidgetInterface;

class ImageWidget implements WidgetInterface
{

    protected $_templates;

    public function __construct($templates)
    {
        $this->_templates = $templates;
    }

    public function render(array $data, ContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data += [
            'name' => '',
        ];
        return $this->_templates->format('myTestTemp', [
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'attrs' => $this->_templates->formatAttributes($data, ['name'])
        ]);
    }

    public function secureFields(array $data)
    {
        return [$data['name']];
    }
}
?>
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot find template named 'myTestTemp'.

I don't know where should I put my template or what is this template at all
(is it like cakephp normal template?)

my template file is like this:

```
//in myTestTemp.ctp file
<p>some html for test</p>
```

I tried to put file in these directories and it doesn't work

1. src/Template
2. src/View
3. src/View/Widget

thanks

Comment: Your question lacks the source of the problem, ie the part where you define the usage of a (string) template named `myTestTemp`. ps, wehenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Comment: sorry i missed it during the copy and paste . thanks for the note .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other widget, your widget works with string templates, and it relies on the template being set in the form helper (respectively to be set on the `\Cake\View\StringTemplate` object that is being passed to the widgets constructor), like for example:

```
$this->Form->setTemplates([
    'myTestTemp' => '<p {{attrs}}>some html for test</p>'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Building a Widget Class](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#building-a-widget-class)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**